# Drawing SVG Density Chart

Tags: html, css, svg, charts

i need to figure out how to get this chart in SVG Format. I almost got it, but i need to perfectly match each sides. When it goes up and down.

[image]

```html
<div class='chart'>
  <svg viewbox='0 0 560 260'>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#92B6E5" />
          <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#92D2E5" />
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#82E5DE" />
          <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#F7C783" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#B5ADA5" />
      </linearGradient>
      <filter id='dropshadow'>
        <feGaussianBlur in='SourceAlpha' stdDeviation='3'></feGaussianBlur>
        <feOffset dx='0' dy='0' result='offsetblur'></feOffset>
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncA slope='0.2' type='linear'></feFuncA>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode></feMergeNode>
          <feMergeNode in='SourceGraphic'></feMergeNode>
        </feMerge>
      </filter>
    </defs>
    <g class='datasets'>
      <path class='dataset' d='M 0 260 C 1 264 60 241 82 228 C 125 205 115 211 158 184 C 202 160 185 170 213 155 C 261 136 287 138 317 151 C 361 175 347 165 424 212 C 484 243 505 242 554 260 L 0 260 Z' id='dataset-1'></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I just need to modify correctly just this part:

```
<path class='dataset' d='M 0 260 C 1 264 60 241 82 228 C 125 205 115 211 158 184 C 202 160 185 170 213 155 C 261 136 287 138 317 151 C 361 175 347 165 424 212 C 484 243 505 242 554 260 L 0 260 Z' id='dataset-1'></path>
```

Comment: Got an editor like Adobe Illustrator? It makes it much easier, can spot you later when I get some free time if you don't.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thank you, no i dont have an editor. I just tried out with this online tool: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris W. is 100% correct, using a vector editor like Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, or Affinity Designer will make your life much easier when working with complex shapes in SVG. However, for simple shapes like this it doesn't hurt to understand the inner-workings of SVG curves. Not only will it help you malke mathematically perfect shapes but your code will also (usually) be much smaller than what an editor will produce.

The example I'm showing here is only one possible approach out of many to accomplishing this shape. I'll explain the procedure and series of commands briefly but I've also included a second copy of your shape with comments and additional shapes to highlight what the control points are doing (this helps me visualize SVG code).

First it moves to a point at x0, y 100 and draws a relative cubic curve (c) whose first control point is right 100px from the start point with no vertical change and whose second control point is right 180px and up 90px from the start point. The following s curve assumes that it will reflect the previous control point of the c curve before it so it only needs it's second control point and end point specified both of which are designated relative to the end point of the c curve and mirror the previous control points of the c curve. The rest is an absolute vertical line (V) to the bottom of the SVG, an absolute horizontal line to the bottom left corner (H) and a Z to close the path. SVG is awesome, hope this helps you.

```css
svg {overflow: visible;}
```

```html
<p>The shape</p>
<div class='chart'>
  <svg viewbox='0 0 560 110'>
    <path d="
      M0 100
      c100 0, 180 -90, 280 -90
            s180 90, 280 90
            V110
            H0
      Z
    " style="fill: #ccc"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<p>With visual control points and comments</p>
<div class='chart'>
  <svg viewbox='0 0 560 110'>
    <path d="
      M0 100
      c100 0, 180 -90, 280 -90
            s180 90, 280 90
            V110
            H0
      Z
    " style="fill: #ccc"/>
        
        <!-- M0 100 -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="100" fill="green" r="2" />
        
        <!-- c100 0 -->
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" fill="red" r="2" />
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
        
        <!-- 180 -90, 280 -90 -->
        <circle cx="180" cy="10" fill="red" r="2" />
        <line x1="180" y1="10" x2="280" y2="10" stroke="red" />
        <circle cx="280" cy="10" fill="red" r="2" />
        
        <!-- Assumed to be a reflection of the previous control point by the following s curve -->
        <line x1="280" y1="10" x2="380" y2="10" stroke="blue" />
        <circle cx="380" cy="10" fill="blue" r="2" />
        
        <!-- s180 90 the second control point of the s curve (the only one you specify)-->
        <line x1="460" y1="100" x2="560" y2="100" stroke="red" />
        <circle cx="460" cy="100" fill="red" r="2" />
        
        <!-- 280 90 this is the end point of the s curve -->
        <circle cx="560" cy="100" fill="purple" r="2" />
        
  </svg>
</div>
```